# How to check URL to contain special characters on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I need to redirect all URLs that contain `/../` or `/../../*` string match to 403 page with .htaccess config.

For example when user type `https://example.com/index.php/../../js/sample.js` on browser URL, I need to redirect to 403 Forbidden page and just `https://example.com/js/sample.js` URL is valid, I need to prevent access Js and other directories and files like `../../` on URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i use this rule to achieve my question answer, I hope to help you if you have same question:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/\.\./ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /404.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/\.\./ - [R=403,NC,L]
```

will match

```
https://example.com/index.php/../js/sample.js
https://example.com/index.php/../../js/sample.js
```